# reading json and converting to HTML - polymer

Tags: polymer

I am trying to read local json file and convert it to HTML layout

I was able to read JSON from local but struggling to read and render on UI

HTML:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.5.0/lib/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.5.0/lib/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.5.0/lib/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">

</head>
<body>

<template is="dom-bind">

    <iron-ajax
            auto
            url="properties.json"
            last-response="{{data}}"
            handle-as="json">
    </iron-ajax>

 <div><span>{{data}}</span></div>
    <!-- <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}">
        <div><span>{{item.name}}</span></div>
    </template> -->

</template>

<script>
    (function (document) {
        'use strict';

        var app = document.querySelector('#app');

        window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
            var ironAjax = document.querySelector('iron-ajax');
            ironAjax.addEventListener('response', function() {
                console.log(ironAjax.lastResponse);
            });
            ironAjax.generateRequest();
        });

    })(document);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

properties.json file

```
{
  "main":{
    "header":{
      "label"     :"Employee Template",
       "logo":"abc.png"
    },
    "footer":{
      "label"     :"2017 All rights reserved.",
      "author":"abc"
    },
    "menu":[
      {
        "label":"Add",
        "url":"/Add"
      },
      {
        "label":"Delete",
        "url":"/Delete"
      }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to render the above json as below HTML

```
<header><h1>{{Employee.header.label}}</h1>
<img src={{Employee.header.logo}}>
</header>
<ul>
<li>{{Employee.menu[0].label}}</li>
<li>{{Employee.menu[0].label}}</li>
</ul>
<footer><h1>{{Employee.footer.label}}</h1>
<div>{{Employee.footer.author}}></div>
</footer>
```

I tried iron-ajax for rendering, but it works only on array of objects and not reading through the json and didnt find much information on documentation

Answer (score 0):

At first, you are propably missing `main` in all bindings? according to your json the hiearchy is `main.header.label` and not `header.label`.

Another issue: When you are pointing to some index of array in bindings you are using `{{Employee.menu[0].label}}` but it should be `{{Employee.menu.0.label}}`. Remember this, because once you will use array mutation methods, it will be same.

If your JSON's structure is always like that and never changes, then it's super simple and you have already did, what you wanted. If your JSON's structure can change to something more complex, then you will have to propably write your own parser. which means, iterating all keys insinde json, creating elements and putting content in it. It will be a little bit harder, but it is possible.

I don't know how your json can look like so i won't write you parser. You will have to try it on your own.

It will start something like:

```
for(var key in this.Employee.main) {
  var el = document.createElement(key);

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is an fiddle with an working example of your code: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dvLjv4n1/)
The fiddle is ab bit different since i have no clue how to do ajax in fiddle but your code sould look like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-
      cdn/1.5.0/lib/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-
  cdn/1.5.0/lib/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-
  cdn/1.5.0/lib/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">

</head>
<body>

<template is="dom-bind">

<iron-ajax
        auto
        url="properties.json"
        last-response="{{data}}"
        handle-as="json">
</iron-ajax>

<header><h1>{{Employee.header.label}}</h1>
    <img src={{Employee.header.logo}}>
</header>
<ul>
    <li>{{data.main.menu.0.label}}</li>
    <li>{{data.main.menu.0.label}}</li>
</ul>
<footer><h1>{{data.main.footer.label}}</h1>
<div>{{data.main.footer.author}}></div>
</footer>

</template>

<script>
(function (document) {
    'use strict';

    var app = document.querySelector('#app');

    window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
        var ironAjax = document.querySelector('iron-ajax');
        ironAjax.addEventListener('response', function() {
            console.log(ironAjax.lastResponse);
        });
        ironAjax.generateRequest();
    });

})(document);

</script>
</body>
</html>`
```